# Using __declspec(nothrow) on functions that return references

Tags: c++, visual-c++, declspec

I'd like to apply `__declspec(nothrow)` on some of my member functions that return object references. For example, I'd like to add it to this function (in MyClass.h):

```
CMyClass& operator= ( IN UInt32 nValue )
{
    return ( SetValue ( nValue ) );
};
```

The [VC++ documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49147z04%28VS.90%29.aspx) that I need to add it after the return type of the function like so:

`return-type __declspec(nothrow) [call-convention] function-name ([argument-list])`

If I follow this, most of my functions work fine with `__declspec(nothrow)`. However, when I do that for the above member function (or any others that return a `CMyClass&`), I get compile errors:

`error C2059: syntax error : '__declspec(nothrow)'`

I can put it in front of the return type and it compiles then but the documentation also says that if a __declspec() is placed in the wrong place, the compiler may ignore it without warning or error.

What's the right way of using `__declspec(nothrow)`?

Comment: Why not use the standard-compliant `throw()` marking?

Comment: This is a pretty pointless exercise.  The MSVC compiler allows *nothrow* declarations but is part of a group of Real Compiler Implementations that treat the declaration as bs.  They got more credit in C++11, exception specifications are deprecated.  The new keyword is *noexcept*.  Don't bother.

Comment: Well, neither throw() nor noexcept works in VC++, while __declspec(nothrow) does.

Comment: @Hans Passant: MSVC doesn't completely ignore empty `throw()` specifier, it just implements it in non-standard way. In MSVC `throw()` allows the compiler to omit stack unwinding code, which is similar to `noexcept`. And according to my tests `throw()` and `__declspec(nothrow)` are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe (but am not 100% certain) the correct syntax is:

```
CMyClass __declspec(nothrow) & operator= ( IN UInt32 nValue )
```

It seems that the compiler follows the same rule for function declarations as it does for simple declarations, and the `&` (or `*`) goes after the `declspec`.  This matches some of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

> The __declspec keywords should be placed at the beginning of a simple declaration. The compiler ignores, without warning, any __declspec keywords placed after * or & and in front of the variable identifier in a declaration.

As others have pointed out, though, this is something of a waste of time.  `throw()` doesn't have the same odd parsing issues, and [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49147z04%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) specifically states that it is equivalent.

> Given the following preprocessor directive, the three function declarations below are equivalent:
>
> > #define WINAPI __declspec(nothrow) __stdcall
> >
> > void WINAPI f1();
> >     void __declspec(nothrow) __stdcall f2();
> >     void __stdcall f3() throw();

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll try it this way. I read the docs but I guess that part you quoted didn't stick. I'll see if I get equivalent assembler output for `throw()` and `_declspec(nothrow)`.